# How test a forkJoin inside a ngRX effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, ngrx

I'm trying to test a ngrx effect with a forkjoin but I can not make it work. This is the code:

```
requestVacationDays$ = createEffect(
        () =>
            this.action$.pipe(
                ofType(VacationsActions.RequestVacationDays),
                switchMap(action => {
                    const httpRequests: Observable<any>[] = [];
                    action.requestedDays.forEach(request => {
                        httpRequests.push(this.vacationService.requestVacationDay(request));
                    });
                    return forkJoin(httpRequests).pipe(
                        switchMap(res => {
                            return [ModalActions.OpenModal({
                                header: 'Requested vacations',
                                message: 'All vacations has been requested correctly.'
                            }), VacationsActions.GetUserVacations()];
                        }),
                    );
                })
            ), { dispatch: true }
    );
```

And this is the test (it is not finished yet, but it does not reach the switchMap inside the forkJoin):

```
fit('should request several vacation days', () => {
        actions$ = of(vacationActions.RequestVacationDays({ requestedDays: ['2020-09-25', '2020-09-26'] }));
        const vacationServiceSpy = spyOn(vacationService, 'requestVacationDay').and.returnValue(cold('-a', { a: null}));
        effects.requestVacationDays$.subscribe(action => {
            expect(vacationServiceSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`forkJoin` only emits once its source observables have signalled completion. In your test you're only emitting the value `null` - you also need to signal completion afterwards